# Given $S_n=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$ show that $\mathbb{E}[S_n^4]=\mathcal{O}(n^2)$

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with **mean zero** and **finite fourth moment**. Let $S_n=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$.

Show that $$\mathbb{E}[S_{_n}^4]=\mathcal{O}(n^2)$$

I feel like this is more of a calculus problem but I don't know how to show this (simple) fact.

Comment: This is *not* true as stated. Are they zero-mean? If not... take the trivial $X_i = 1$ a.s.,so that $S_n = n$ a.s., as a counterexample.

Comment: BrianMoehring and Clement C. you are right, the mean has to be zero. I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than being a "calculus problem", it actually ends up being a bit of combinatorics.

When you apply the multinomial theorem to expand $S_n^4$, the only monomials that will result in a non-zero expectation must have each distinct variable appearing with even degree. This leaves either $X_i^4$ or $X_i^2X_j^2$. There are $O(n)$ of the first kind and $O(n^2)$ of the second kind.

Comment: That's a good answer to a different question. As stated, there is no zero-mean assumption, and the thing to prove is false.

Comment: @ClementC. The question has been edited to assume that the $\mathbb E[X_1]=0$, now is it correct?

Comment: @ClementC. it was clear that this was the question the OP meant to ask, and I figured it was a matter of time before the question was fixed rather than make a big deal about it...

Comment: @pre-kidney could you explain how did you get $O(n^2)$. It's because $\binom{n}{2} \in O(n^2)$?

Comment: @Babado Yes, precisely.